# How Can I make A condition to stop my timer in 10 seconds

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a button to start the timer:

```
Private Sub StartBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Start.Click

    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

And I have a Timer which contains random number in the range **0 - 75**:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = random.Next(0, 75)
End Sub
```

How Can I give a condition for 10 seconds my label or my timer will stop.

Comment: Look into time span...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare an integer in your timer function and increment it by one every time the timer ticks. You could then evaluate the value of the integer every time the timer ticks. When it reaches 10, you could then use Timer1.Enabled = False. For example: 
first, declare the integer variable.

```
Public timerCount As Integer = 0
```

Then, in your timer function:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = random.Next(0, 75)
    If timerCount = 10 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
        timerCount = timerCount + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

So in this case, the new timer function will check if the variable is equal to 10. If it is, the timer will disable. For this function to work, you will have to set your timer to tick every second.